# shorten ng-repeat variable with limitTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my DB I have Datastructure like this

```
"Projects":[{
    "Year2016":[{"Name": "Project1"},{"Name": "Project2"}],
    "Year2017":[{"Name": "Project1"},{"Name": "Project2"}]
           }]
```

with `ng-repeat` i go

```
ng-repeat="year in Projects"
<b>{{year | limitTo:4:6}}</b>
```

instead of `2016` i get the whole `{"Year2016":.....}`

if i put the query response in the code as a string it works as suspected but

for some reason the `limitTo` is not working on the new `ng-repeat` "variable"

Is it possible at all?

Comment: to clarify the "year in Projects" contains the curved brackets and the qutaion marks since the query response is actually a Json Object so changing limitTo:4:4 is neither correct nor is it doing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a **(key, value)** syntax `ng-repeat` to loop through *json object array* with the **keys**.

refer the below example:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      "Projects": [{
        "Year2016": [{
          "Name": "Project1"
        }, {
          "Name": "Project2"
        }],
        "Year2017": [{
          "Name": "Project1"
        }, {
          "Name": "Project2"
        }]
      }]
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="project in data.Projects">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in project">
      <b>{{key | limitTo:4:4}}</b>
      <div ng-repeat="item in value">
        <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is a really good idea, I think this will work but the actual query response is Projects: [0]: year2016: [0]: Projectname.  i tried your code and i get key=0 and value={"Year2016"... sadly the {{value | limitTo:4:6}} is still not removing anything from the {"Year2016"....

Comment: @LukasTilch sorry for late response.  pay attention that I also used a outside ng-repeat to loop through `Projects` array, then the inside ng-repeat loop through json object array.

Comment: thanks for the response, I can't wrap my head around that for `{{year}}` it actually prints out what is want `{"Year2016": and so on` so the information I need is in `year` but the `limitTo:X:X` isn't doing anything. it still displays `{"Year2016": and so on`

Comment: @LukasTilch you can copy/paster the example and change the variable name to see.

Comment: @LukasTilch the reason limitTo didn't work is because it's target is an object not string or array.

Comment: thank you so much that actually works. but after that I have another `ng-repeat="detail in year.year2016"` to list the projects in it. how would i adapt it?

Comment: @LukasTilch  then you will need a third nested ng-repeat. check the example.

Comment: got it working, but now the rest of my code is messing it up. I'll leave that for another day. Thanks again for your patience

Answer (score 0):

last field id for starting index so your ng repeat should be

```
ng-repeat="year in Projects"
<b>{{year | limitTo:4:4}}</b>
```

Comment: the query response is {"Year2016":[{"Name": "Project1"},{"Name": "Project2"}],"Year2017":[{"Name": "Project1"},{"Name": "Project2"} so i need to remove the first 6 characters. but the limitTo ist not doing anything

Comment: @Lukas Tilch What exactly u need? 2016 or 16?

Comment: I need 2016, the variable year contains {"Year2016"...  on the next repeat {"Year2017"... so I need to remove the first 6 characters. the problem is that the limitTo does not work on my year variable. it doesn't remove anything from the Json i get as a query response.

Comment: @Lukas Tilch  Are you mad or trying to made us? You need 2016, as you said, so you just need to escape 4 characters "Y", "E", "A", "R". what other two you need to escape?

Comment: @geminiousgoel well i need to remove " { "," " ","Y", "E", "A", "R" but that is not the issue. If i write {{ '{"Year2016" ' | limitTo:4:6}} it is working just fine. but if i use teh year varaiable is specified in the ng-repeat it is not doing anything with the content of the varaible